# Extracting values from list of dicts to be used in calculation

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

My input data is a list of dicts (`matches`), where each dict has 2 possible places for a record to show up as well as a correlating factor between the two and their respective data sources:

```
[
  { 'r1': record_1, 'r2': record_2, corr: 85, 'r1_source': source_1, 'r2_source': source_2 },
  { 'r1': record_1, 'r2': record_3, corr: 90, 'r1_source': source_1, 'r2_source': source_3 },
  { 'r1': record_2, 'r2': record_3, corr: 77, 'r1_source': source_2, 'r2_source': source_3 },
  ...
]
```

Each `record` is represented by a list which comes from a finite list of unique `records`.

The structure of my desired output data is a list of dicts where each unique `record` has itself, its source, and its average correlating factor:

```
[
  { 'record': record_1, 'source': source_1, 'avg': (85 + 90) / 2 },
  { 'record': record_2, 'source': source_2, 'avg': (85 + 77) / 2 },
  { 'record': record_3, 'source': source_3, 'avg': (90 + 77) / 2 },
]
```

My current solution:

```
def average_record_from_match_value(matches):
    averaged_recs = []

    for match in matches:
        # Q1 
        if [rec for rec in averaged_recs if rec['record'] == match['r1']] == []:
            a_recs = []
            # Q2
            a_recs.extend([m['corr'] for m in matches if m['r1'] == match['r1']])
            a_recs.extend([m['corr'] for m in matches if m['r2'] == match['r1']])
            # Q3
            r1_value = sum(a_recs) / len(a_recs)
            averaged_recs.append({ 'record': match['r1'],
                                   'source': match['r1_source'],
                                   'match_value': r1_value,
                                   'record_value': r1_value})
        if [rec for rec in averaged_recs if rec['record'] == match['r2']] == []:
            b_recs = []
            b_recs.extend([m['corr'] for m in matches if m['r1'] == match['r2']])
            b_recs.extend([m['corr'] for m in matches if m['r2'] == match['r2']])
            r2_value = sum(b_recs) / len(b_recs)
            averaged_recs.append({ 'record': match['r2'],
                                   'source': match['r2_source'],
                                   'match_value': r2_value,
                                   'record_value': r2_value})

    return averaged_recs
```

This works, but I'm sure it can be improved. My questions as labeled by the comments above are:

1. Is there a better way to enforce uniqueness here? I have a gut
   feeling that I don't need to be traversing my `averaged_recs` list
   for every match.
2. Can I corral all of these `records` without looping
   over them twice like this?
3. Can/should this average calculation be combined with the previous list extension?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

it's a little hard to do it with list comprehension but I managed to write it with a few less line and hopefully clutter using a tmp dict to sort the keys

```
lst = [
  { 'r1': 'record_1', 'r2': 'record_2', 'corr': 85, 'r1_source': 'source_1', 'r2_source': 'source_2' },
  { 'r1': 'record_1', 'r2': 'record_3', 'corr': 90, 'r1_source': 'source_1', 'r2_source': 'source_3' },
  { 'r1': 'record_2', 'r2': 'record_3', 'corr': 77, 'r1_source': 'source_2', 'r2_source': 'source_3' },
]

tmp_dict = {}
for d in lst:
    if d['r1'] not in tmp_dict.keys():
        tmp_dict[d['r1']] = {}
        tmp_dict[d['r1']]['corr'] = list()
        tmp_dict[d['r1']]['source'] = d['r1_source']

    if d['r2'] not in tmp_dict.keys():
        tmp_dict[d['r2']] = {}
        tmp_dict[d['r2']]['corr'] = list()
        tmp_dict[d['r2']]['source'] = d['r2_source']

    tmp_dict[d['r1']]['corr'].append(d['corr'])
    tmp_dict[d['r2']]['corr'].append(d['corr'])


print [{ 'record': k, 'source': tmp_dict[k]['source'], 'avg': sum(tmp_dict[k]['corr'])/float(len(tmp_dict[k]['corr'])) } for k in tmp_dict.keys()]
```

Answer (score 1):

My idea,
We can loop the list to generate one dict for all r1, r2, if r1, append it to the head of the list, if r2, add it to the tail.

Then loop this dict to get the output you expected.

```
from collections import defaultdict
test = [
  { 'r1': 'record_1', 'r2': 'record_2', 'corr': 85, 'r1_source': 'source_1', 'r2_source': 'source_2' },
  { 'r1': 'record_1', 'r2': 'record_3', 'corr': 90, 'r1_source': 'source_1', 'r2_source': 'source_3' },
  { 'r1': 'record_2', 'r2': 'record_3', 'corr': 77, 'r1_source': 'source_2', 'r2_source': 'source_3' },
]
temp = defaultdict(list)
for item in test:
    temp[item['r1']].insert(0, item)
    temp[item['r2']].append(item)

result = []
for key, value in temp.items():
    new_item = {}
    new_item['avg'] = sum(list(map(lambda item: item['corr'], value)))*1.0/len(value)
    new_item['record'] = key
    new_item['source'] = value[0]['r1_source'] if key == value[0]['r1'] else value[0]['r2_source']
    result.append(new_item)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'avg': 87.5, 'record': 'record_1', 'source': 'source_1'}, {'avg': 81.0, 'record': 'record_2', 'source': 'source_2'}, {'avg': 83.5, 'record': 'record_3', 'source': 'source_3'}]
[Finished in 0.175s]
```

**Update 1:**

If r1 and r2 are the list, we can convert it to tuple, then convert it back when calculate the output.

so the codes will be like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
record1 = [1, 2, 3]
record2 = [4, 5, 6]
record3 = [7, 8, 9]
test = [
  { 'r1': record1, 'r2': record2, 'corr': 85, 'r1_source': 'source_1', 'r2_source': 'source_2' },
  { 'r1': record1, 'r2': record3, 'corr': 90, 'r1_source': 'source_1', 'r2_source': 'source_3' },
  { 'r1': record2, 'r2': record3, 'corr': 77, 'r1_source': 'source_2', 'r2_source': 'source_3' },
]
temp = defaultdict(list)
for item in test:
    temp[tuple(item['r1'])].insert(0, item)
    temp[tuple(item['r2'])].append(item)

result = []
for key, value in temp.items():
    new_item = {}
    new_item['avg'] = sum(list(map(lambda item: item['corr'], value)))*1.0/len(value)
    new_item['record'] = list(key)
    new_item['source'] = value[0]['r1_source'] if list(key) == value[0]['r1'] else value[0]['r2_source']
    result.append(new_item)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'avg': 87.5, 'record': [1, 2, 3], 'source': 'source_3'}, {'avg': 81.0, 'record': [4, 5, 6], 'source': 'source_3'}, {'avg': 83.5, 'record': [7, 8, 9], 'source': 'source_3'}]
[Finished in 0.178s]
```

Comment: A cool idea, but your records in this example are strings, but remember each record is a list. Since a list is an unhashable type, it cannot be the key of your temp dictionary. Replacing `'record_1'` with `['record_1']` causes a `TypeError`.

Comment: @Eqomatic, updated my answer to support if r1, r2 are the list.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - A dictionary is inherently made by unique elements so I don't believe you need to recheck it this way. You're also iterating through averaged recs, which is empty.

Q2 - You could use or in the if statement
`[m['corr'] for m in matches if m['r1'] == match['r1'] or m['r2'] == match['r1']]`

Q3 - I don't really think you need another way to do it